# Intrinsic Convert Text to Number - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

If I have Text in cells that I want to convert to numbers, I usually write little subs like:

```
Sub ConvertToNumber()
    With ActiveCell
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = Trim(.Text)
    End With
End Sub
```

I recently discovered that I could perform the conversion without any custom coding and without any **VBA.**  I can do this by selecting *Convert to Number* from the warning context menu:

[image]

My question is how can I get to this functionality from **VBA?**  Is there any "built-in" **Property** or **Method** associated with the **Range** Object that performs the conversion directly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class VBA.Conversion contains a host of conversion functions, including `CInt()` and `CDbl()` that seem particularly suited to your question:

```
CBool(expression)
CByte(expression)
CChar(expression)
CDate(expression)
CDbl(expression)
CDec(expression)
CInt(expression)
CLng(expression)
CObj(expression)
CSByte(expression)
CShort(expression)
CSng(expression)
CStr(expression)
CUInt(expression)
CULng(expression)
CUShort(expression)
```

Comment: Thanks.....the approach works for cells with Prefix Characters, but not with cells formatted as *Text*

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: Pleas explain - it works fine for me in EXCEL 2010